# Doubt in substitution for a Gamma Function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

[image]

My Doubt : I just want to know what kind of substitution should one take in this problem, after that I think I'll manage this

Comment: You want to rewrite $3^{-4x^2}$ as $e^{-(kx)^2}$.  Can you solve for $k$?   Then the obvious substitution is $y=kx$

Comment: If you want to get the Gamma function, try $y=(kx)^2$

Comment: What does this have to do with the gamma function?

Comment: $3^{-4x^2}=e^{-4(\ln{3})x^2}$ and know let $x=\frac{u}{2\sqrt{\ln{3}}}$.

Comment: What does this have to do with the gamma function? – 
David C. Ullrich
Please Check the answer by Frank to see the relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral can be transformed into the gamma function with some algebraic manipulation and a straightforward substitution. First, recall that the gamma function is defined as

$$\Gamma(n+1)=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}x^ne^{-x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Our integrand has an exponential term with a base of $3$ and in order to convert our integral into the form above, it must take on a base of $e$. Therefore, rewrite the power as

$$3^{-4x^2}=e^{-4x^2\log 3}\qquad\implies\qquad I=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}e^{-4x^2\log 3}\,\mathrm dx$$

Next, make the substitution $t=4x^2\log 3$ so

$$x=\frac 12\sqrt{\frac t{\log 3}}\qquad\implies\qquad\mathrm dx=\frac {\mathrm dt}{4\sqrt{t\log 3}}$$

The integral $I$ becomes

\begin{align*}I & =\frac 1{4\sqrt{\log 3}}\int\limits_0^{+\infty}t^{-1/2}e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt\\ & =\frac 1{4\sqrt{\log 3}}\Gamma\left(\frac 12\right)\\ & =\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{4\sqrt {\log 3}}\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks sir , I was stuck with the substitution part

Answer (score 0):

That integral is not so related with gamma function, but Gauss error function. Taking $u=2x$ you get the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^{u^2}}du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4\sqrt{\log 3}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{\log 3 }}{\sqrt{\pi}3^{u^2}}du$$
where $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{\log 3 }}{\sqrt{\pi}3^{u^2}}du=erf(\sqrt{\log 3}u)$$
So $$\int_{0}^{\infty}3^{-4x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4\sqrt{\log 3}}(\lim_{u\to\infty} erf(\sqrt{\log 3}u)-erf(0))=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4\sqrt{\log 3}}$$

Comment: He asks for a simple substitution.

Comment: Is there a more simple substitution that $u=2x$?

Comment: Is it the most useful substition?

Comment: But sir the question is from the chapter of Gamma Function ( So maybe it actually is related to Gamma Function)

Comment: Frank's answer shows that it is related to the gamma function.

Comment: Italics on erf don't come out right.  Use $\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{\log 3}u)$ and not $erf(\sqrt{\log 3}u)$ .